# read and insert xml file's records using php mysql via For statement not Foreach Loop

Tags: php

Let say I have an xml file containing 200 records, I want to read and insert 120 records into mysql using `for` statement not `foreach` statement. I knw how to do this using foreach statement which always reads and inserts the entire records and I don't want that.
My code using `foreach` statement is working. I want similar code using 'For statement'.

```
<?php

$xml=simplexml_load_file("c:\abc.xml");

$fd=count($xml);
foreach ( $xml as $bado)
{

    $name=$bado->name;
    $sex=$bado->sex;
    $address=$bado->address;

    $result=mysql_query("insert into abc (name,sex,address) values ($name,$sex,$address)",$con)

    echo $fd." "."Records successfully added";
}

? >
```

Note: if I don't want the entire records to be added, then d use of For loop statement, I think should be d way out or any other best options ?

Answer (score 0):

Foreach could be used for this as well.  It doesn't HAVE to loop over and insert all records.  However, here is how it can be done with a for statement

```
//indexes are 0-indexed, meaning $xml[0] = first, $xml[119] = last (for 120 records)
for($i=0;$i<119;$i++) {
  $user = $xml[$i]; //Provided that the element you are looping over is an array of entities
  //Database insert logic here
}
```

Please, please for the love of little puppies consider PDO and prepared statements, rather than using deprecated mysql_* functions, and unsanitized input.  If your XML contains the name  "O'malley" it WILL break your query!!

Updated to include sample for foreach and with fields referenced:

```
//indexes are 0-indexed, meaning $xml[0] = first, $xml[119] = last (for 120 records)
    for($i=0;$i<119;$i++) {
       $user    = $xml[$i]; //Provided that the element you are looping over is an array of entities
       $name    = $user->name;
       $sex     = $user->sex;
       $address = $user->address;

        $result = mysql_query("insert into abc (name,sex,address) values ($name,$sex,$address)",$con)


    }
echo $i+1." "."Records successfully added";
```

With Foreach:

```
$limit = 119;
$i     = 0;

   //indexes are 0-indexed, meaning $xml[0] = first, $xml[119] = last (for 120 records)
        for($xml as $user) {
           if($i > $limit) {
             break;
           } 
           $name    = $user->name;
           $sex     = $user->sex;
           $address = $user->address;

           $result = mysql_query("insert into abc (name,sex,address) values ($name,$sex,$address)",$con)
           $i++;
        }
echo $i+1." "."Records successfully added";
```

Comment: jc, please
1. let me have d sample of d insert statement showing each corresponding fields. Thanks 
2. how can d above question be explicitly  achieved using d Foreach statement ?

Comment: Thanks, you d Big 'BOSS'

Comment: Prof. JC, please from d above case, if my database contains some previous records, how can I query each db row before new record can be inserted from my xml file to prevent duplicated insertions for every xml file load or read sessions. Thanks. Prof.